# Problema en resultado "contando vocales" en función de javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

He creado en Javascript una función polivalente que muestra en pantalla un mensaje distinto según el valor introducido en una variable: un número, un valor booleano y un string. Mi problema es que, en el caso del string, la función tiene que contar el número de **vocales minúsculas sin tilde** de la variable cadena pero tal como tengo ahora el código siempre me devuelve 0.
Seguro que tengo algo mal en el código pero no sé qué es. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.
Os cuelgo mi código, tal como lo tengo ahora:

```
<body>
<div id="caja"></div>
<!-- Código Javascript -->
<script>
    var cadena = "mi nombre es Pedro"; // valores: true, false, 6, "mi nombre es Pedro"
    function polivalente(cadena) {
        switch (true) {
            case (!isNaN(cadena) && cadena != true && cadena != false):
                return (`El cuadrado del argumento es ${cadena * cadena}`);
                break;
            case (cadena):
                return (`El contrario del argumento es <i>false</i>`);
                break;
            case (!cadena):
                return (`El contrario del argumento es <i>true</i>`);
                break;
            default:
                const vocales = "aeiou";
                let cantidadVocales = 0;
                for (let vocales of cadena) {
                    if (vocales.includes(cadena.toLowerCase())) {
                        cantidadVocales++;
                    }
                }
                return (`La cadena del argumento tiene ${cantidadVocales} vocales minúsculas`);
        }
    }
    var caja = document.getElementById("caja");
    caja.innerHTML = polivalente(cadena);
</script>
```

Comment: tienes que calcular en numero de letras en minuscula o el numero de vocales en minuscula?

Comment: el número de vocales en minúscula que hay en la variable cadena. Gracias, corrijo el enunciado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar expresiones regulares

**Opción 1**

```js
let str = "TextO de Prueba";
let number = str.replace(/[^aeiou]/g, "").length;
console.log(number);
```

**Opción 2**

```js
let str = "TextO de Prueba";
let number = str.match(/[aeiou]/g)
if(number != null){
    console.log(number.length);
}
```

**Opción 3**

```js
let str = "TextO de Prueba";
const vocales = "aeiou";
let cantidadVocales = 0;
for (let caracter of str) {
   if (vocales.includes(caracter,0)) {
      cantidadVocales++;
   }
}
console.log(cantidadVocales);
```

Comment: He probado a integrar tu OPCIÓN 1 en mi código y funciona. Gracias :-)

Comment: ¿Habría algún modo de hacer lo mismo utilizando un bucle for, tal como he intentado yo?

Comment: Edito la respuesta y añado una tercera opcion

Comment: He probado tu nueva OPCIÓN 3 y funciona perfectamente :-)
¡Solucionado! Muchas gracias por dedicarme tu tiempo.